# how to send mail using godaddy cpanel mail in django

Tags: python, django, email, cpanel, godaddy-api

I created an email on godaddy c-panel hosting . I have written some codes in Django to send mail using this mail and in recipients mail I have 3 mails and one is c-panel email. It is sending mail to only c-panel mail not to others two.

Also I have configured DNS and forwarder but that's also not working.

> Can you tell me What am I doing wrong? Please give the solutions for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.